# Checking if a number divides evenly by many others

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, program-entry-point, iostream

I have a programming problem that wants me to check of the 30,000 Hexagonal numbers (given by the formula: H(n) = n(2n-1) ), how many of them are divisible by the numbers 1 through 12.

I have code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hex, count = 0;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 30000; n++)
    {
        hex = n * ((2 * n) - 1);

        if (hex % 1 == 0 && hex % 2 == 0 && hex % 3 == 0 && hex % 4 == 0 && hex % 5 == 0 && hex % 6 == 0 && hex % 7 == 0 && hex % 8 == 0 && hex % 9 == 0 && hex % 10 == 0 && hex % 11 == 0 && hex % 12 == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Now I know the check I have right now in my if statement is very inefficient, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way to check the number? I tried using a for loop but couldn't get it to work (given it only checks 1 number at a time). Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: If a Number divides evenly by 12 then it __must__ also divide evenly by 2, 3, 4 and 6.

Comment: Also you can replace `hex % 2 == 0` by `!(hex % 2)`, etc.

Comment: `hex % 1 == 0` ??? Really? Is it something like `0 == 0`?

Comment: `using namespace std;` and then declaring variables `hex` and `count` is a Manhattan Project waiting to be finished.

Comment: I understand what you're saying VolAnd, putting the %1 was unnecessary, and thanks for the suggestion. Also thanks tkausl, that did shorten it quite a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `a[i] | x` for `1 <= i <= n`, then `lcm(a[1], ..., a[n]) | x`

For this case, just need to check if `lcm(1,2,...,12) | h`, i.e. `h % 27720 == 0`

---

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Comment: I'm just a little confused, how did you get the number 27720? I'm assuming it's divisible by the numbers 1 through 12?

Comment: @Gardenia 27720 is the lease common multiple of 1,2,...12

Comment: The way I approached it, is that you need all the power of primes in 1..12. so you should check for 2³.3².5.7.11 (which is another way of saying "what is the lcm of 1..12?")

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, that's is ony way to calculate lcm

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use another for loop to get rid from the long if statement that you have used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int hex, count = 0;
    int divider = 12;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 30000; n++){
        hex = n * ((2 * n) - 1);

        int subcount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= divider; ++i){
            if (hex % i == 0){
                ++subcount;
                if(subcount == devider){
                     ++count;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: how is different from what posted in question? Here you are doing unnecessary iterations, for example you are checking division by 3 and 4 and 12, if it gets divided by both 3 and 4, it will automatically be divided by 12. Hence calculate the LCM for 1 to 12, check divisibility with that.

Comment: @instance no offense. I agree with your comment. This is just an alternative to achieve target rather than using a long if statement.

Comment: but still your code is wrong, OP wants to find count of numbers which are divisible by ALL numbers from 1 to 12. What you are doing is, for each "hex" you are incrementing "count" if it divides by "i". You need to increment count by 1 only IF it is divisible by all 1 to 12.

Comment: change your if statement to if(hex%i) break; else if(i==divider) count++;